# Can we submit and sign the 8710 in IACRA after the check ride?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-testing, checkride

I work at a 142 school and was told we can submit and esign the 8710 after the check ride.  The digital esignature shows a date time stamp 9-hours after the beginning of the oral and flight exam. I have always had everyone submit and esign the 8710 before any event and completed it after the event with the result.

Thoughts?  Is there any regulation or FAA guidance one way or the other?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Can you clarify what "esign" means here? I'm not sure if you're asking if you can do the checkride first and submit the 8710 in IACRA afterwards? Or if you're submitting the 8710 in IACRA first but not completing some specific part of it until after the checkride?

Comment: E-Sign, using user name and password aka electronic signature.  And correct, checkride first then start the paperwork.  I suspect not, because that would give a 4th option - pretend it never happened, instead of Approval, Disapproval or Discontinuance.  Furthermore, if we wait to do the paperwork after the checkride a disapproved student might be able to claim that the checkride was invalid because they had not signed the paperwork until it was over.

Comment: Thanks, I reworded it a little to reflect what I *think* you mean and hopefully make it easier to get a good answer. If I got it wrong, you can always edit again or roll back my changes.

Comment: Thank you, spot on.